# How to process 2 ranges/lists in sync with each other in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, key-value

I have a file with 2 columns in it: key/value.

```
k1  v1
k2  v2
k3  v3
etc.
```

I am trying to write a script to go thru this file, pulling the matching key/values for me to test with.  My problem is I don't know how to pull the matching sets out to run my test.

I have two failed attempts so hopefully someone can point out my incorrect syntax/logic and correct me.

1) I tried using awk to pull out the keys and values and use a for loop to process

```
k=`awk '{print $1}' file`
v=`awk '{print $2}' file`

for i in {0..10}
do
   echo ${k[$i]}
   echo ${v[$i]}
done
```

However, I don't know how to access/store the values correctly.  Everything is ending up in element 0 of the array.  Is there a way to specify in this setup, to grab "element" 0 from k and v, element 1 from k and v, etc from the list in tandem?

2) I also tried using a while loop to read this

```
while read line
do
   k=`awk '{print $1}' $line`
   v=`awk '{print $2}' $line`
done < file
```

However, this technique seems wrong too since the shell complains that there is no file kX and says:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `k1' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `k1' for reading (No such file or directory)
(repeating for all keys)
```

Technique #1 was me trying to think outside the box to solve this, although it seems tougher to maintain 2 lists in sync to get this done.  I think technique #2 makes more sense to me

```
1) Read the line
2) Separate out the key and value
3) Use the key and value to run my test
4) Go to step 1 until EOF
```

Hopefully someone can help me with my messed up syntax, or teach me a new technique #3 that's more efficient than what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can keys or values have spaces in them?

Comment: no, the keys and values do not have spaces in them.  i think there's either 4 spaces or a tab between the key and value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give multiple arguments to `read`, it will split the input line and assign each variable to the corresponding field of the input.

```
while read k v
do 
  echo Key: $k
  echo Value: $v
done < file
```

If there are more input fields than variables, the last variable gets all the remaining fields.

Your first attempt would have worked if you'd written:

```
k=(`awk '{print $1}' file`)
v=(`awk '{print $2}' file`)
```

The parentheses make it an array instead of a single value.

Your second attempt would have worked if you'd written:

```
k=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}'`
v=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

The 2nd argument to `awk` is a filename, not the input itself; you need to pipe the line to `awk`'s standard input.